# Jquery conflict in dnn module

Tags: dotnetnuke

Hi i am working on dotnetnuke modules . I have developes a module . This module has different effects . I am using different repeaters for different effect . If i add two modules in a single page . Jscript is not working properly . How can i solve this problem .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid jquery conflict in dnn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823908/how-to-avoid-jquery-conflict-in-dnn)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the javascript you're using is being added twice, once for each instance of the module. You should be using RegisterClientScriptBlock and/or RegisterClientScriptInclude from the code-behind in order to add the Javascript to the page. By using that, it will prevent the script from being added twice.

Comment: can u tell me indetail please . how can i use this in code behind

Comment: If i add two modules in a page , javascript calling twice . if i add three modules , javasript is calling thrice . please give me a solution to solve this .

Comment: I have used DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration(); in codebehind for registering sripts