# How to avoid jquery conflict in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am working on dnn modules development. Jquery is calling many times as the number of modules increases on the same page.

```
    (function ($) {  
        $('#grid').hoverfold();
    })(jQuery);
```

This is what I used to avoid conflict. If I use the same for the next effect it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

For example, If you look at `/DesktopModules/Admin/HostSettings/HostSettings.ascx` you will notice that dnn core developers are using following code:

```
(function ($, Sys) {
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    //Your code goes here.
 });
}(jQuery, window.Sys));
```

Apart from this, if you notice the `$(document).ready` function, they are repeating the same code to handle ajax post backs due to update pane. That will ensure your code will work ok even if module is having ajax enabled.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        setUpDnnHostSettings();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
            setUpDnnHostSettings();
        });
    });
```

You can also look at other ascx controls in core in admin folder. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    ...code goes here...
});
```

Try This,

Comment: If you call `jQuery.noConflict()`, that will remove the `jQuery` variable from the page, which will break all other functionality trying to make use of jQuery.